# T-SQL Stored Procedure returned value into variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012-express

I have a simple stored procedure on MS SQL 2012 Express that returns a result doing something like :

```
DECLARE @value INT;
SELECT @value;
```

Meanwhile I am trying to call this stored procedure doing something like

```
DECLARE @result INT;
EXEC @result = SpFoo .....
```

However the value I get on `@result` from the `SpFoo`is 0.

How can I get the real value returned from the Stored Procedure?

Thanks

Comment: That's not *returning* a value (that would be the [`RETURN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) statement). That's producing a *result set*. You can capture that using [`INSERT ... EXEC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

Comment: You could also use an [`OUTPUT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) parameter for this.

Comment: The best idea is convert your sp as function then you can simply return the values where ever you want.when you try to producre result set then you cannot take it inside select.

Comment: Thank you all. I understand the limitations and possibilities now.

Answer (score 0):

First declare @Value as output parameter in your called sp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCallee
@Value INT Output
AS
BEGIN
    set @Value = 1

END
GO
```

Get result like this in caller sp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCaller
AS
BEGIN

    declare @Result as int = 0

    EXEC spCallee @Value = @Result Output

    Select @Result
END
GO
```

[image: For your reference]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to put result to the table and then get it from it:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Result int)
DECLARE @res int

INSERT INTO @tmp
EXECUTE [Procedure]...

SELECT @res = Result
FROM @tmp
```